# How to copy the last row of the datafram and make changes on copied row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
        Commodity Code                                          Commodity  Year   Reporter Reporter ISO         Partner Partner ISO        Export  Import  Re-Export  Re-Import
1564774         270900  Petroleum oils & oils obt. from bituminous min...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Curaçao         CUW  0.000000e+00     2.0        0.0        0.0
1563032         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Belgium         BEL  2.404415e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563066         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          Brazil         BRA  1.067652e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563121         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          Canada         CAN  3.170861e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563177         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           China         CHN  1.014889e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563353         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          France         FRA  0.000000e+00    33.0        0.0        0.0
1563397         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Germany         DEU  2.722320e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563486         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           India         IND  1.494257e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563707         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN        Malaysia         MYS  5.509827e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563760         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN     Netherlands         NLD  4.208213e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563840         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN       Nicaragua         NIC  3.877573e+07     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564055         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN       Singapore         SGP  2.000000e+00     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564129         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           Spain         ESP  1.559714e+09     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564185         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          Sweden         SWE  6.652943e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564281         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN             USA         USA  2.815425e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564372         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN  United Kingdom         GBR  3.303344e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563307         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN  Dominican Rep.         DOM  6.038139e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563590         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           Japan         JPN  4.834996e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564420         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Uruguay         URY  4.908717e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564655         270900  Petroleum oils & oils obt. from bituminous min...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Jamaica         JAM  7.417692e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
```

I want to copy the last row of the data frame and change the values. I did copy the last row with:

```
other_country_row = group.iloc[-1:]
```

which gave me:

```
            Commodity Code                                          Commodity  Year   Reporter Reporter ISO  Partner Partner ISO       Export  Import  Re-Export  Re-Import
    1564655         270900  Petroleum oils & oils obt. from bituminous min...  2013  Venezuela          VEN  Jamaica         JAM  741769216.0     0.0        0.0        0.0

and I changed values on it, unfortunately, it is not copied and making changes on the last row of the data frame.

        Commodity Code                                          Commodity  Year   Reporter Reporter ISO         Partner Partner ISO        Export  Import  Re-Export  Re-Import
1564774         270900  Petroleum oils & oils obt. from bituminous min...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Curaçao         CUW  0.000000e+00     2.0        0.0        0.0
1563032         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Belgium         BEL  2.404415e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563066         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          Brazil         BRA  1.067652e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563121         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          Canada         CAN  3.170861e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563177         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           China         CHN  1.014889e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563353         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          France         FRA  0.000000e+00    33.0        0.0        0.0
1563397         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Germany         DEU  2.722320e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563486         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           India         IND  1.494257e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563707         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN        Malaysia         MYS  5.509827e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563760         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN     Netherlands         NLD  4.208213e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563840         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN       Nicaragua         NIC  3.877573e+07     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564055         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN       Singapore         SGP  2.000000e+00     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564129         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           Spain         ESP  1.559714e+09     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564185         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN          Sweden         SWE  6.652943e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564281         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN             USA         USA  2.815425e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564372         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN  United Kingdom         GBR  3.303344e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563307         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN  Dominican Rep.         DOM  6.038139e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1563590         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           Japan         JPN  4.834996e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564420         270900  Oils; petroleum oils and oils obtained from bi...  2013  Venezuela          VEN         Uruguay         URY  4.908717e+08     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564655         270900  Petroleum oils & oils obt. from bituminous min...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           Other       Other  1.478252e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
1564655         270900  Petroleum oils & oils obt. from bituminous min...  2013  Venezuela          VEN           Other       Other  1.478252e+10     0.0        0.0        0.0
```

As you can see Jamaice was removed(I want to keep jamaica and add the last row as it is). How can I handle this?

Comment: Assign the new values using iloc: `df.iloc[-1] = [...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `.iloc` with a slice `[:]` will return a mutable reference to the underlying data. What you need is a [`.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```py
other_country_row = group.iloc[-1:].copy()
```

That will return a deep copy of the data by default, which you can safely edit without affecting the original `group` dataframe.